# Updating Symfony from 4.2.1. to 4.2.2. breaks web app

Tags: symfony, symfony4

After updating symfony from 4.2.1. to 4.2.2. with composer, my web app outputs the following error. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Seems like there is a problem with your route or something like that.
Can you post your route config/annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Comment: Consider adding the `cache:clear` call to your post install / update scripts in composer so next time you update it should do this automatically.

Comment: Using symfony flex it does that automatically when you install/update, I think.